# Как зациклить программу в python?

Tags: python, циклы, for, while

Нужен человек разбирающийся в python хотя бы на базовом уровне. Ситуация следующая.
Я только начал учить язык, но столкнулся с маленькой проблемкой. Мне нужно что бы после того как калькулятор сработал, первый вопрос при неправильном ответе дублировался, до тех пор пока ответ будет верный. И так же с вопросом номер два.
Вот код программы (там все предельно просто):

```
a = int( input( "Введи первое значение, бро: "))
b = int( input( "Введи второе значение: "))
what = input( "Введи знак:" )

if what == "+":
    c = a + b
    print("Результат:" + str(c)) 
elif what == "-":
    c = a - b
    print("Результат:" + str(c))
elif what == "*":
    c = a * b
    print("Результат:" + str(c))
elif what == "/":
    c = a / b
    print("Результат:" + str(c)) 
else:
    print("Чел, калькултор еще не такой умный =)")

running = True
for running:

    slovo = input( "Введи кодовое слово, чел:" )

    if slovo == "Дружба":
        print (str("Не разлей вода"))
    else:
        print ("Неправильно, друуг)")
running = False
slovo2 = input( "Может еще какие нибудь слова?:")

if slovo2 == "Учеба":
    print (str("Да, пойду устроюсь в макдональдс"))
else:
    print ("Век учись, век живи Фориз))")
```

---

Я предпринял некоторые попытки решить проблему, как видно в коде, но у меня либо вообще не циклиться, либо циклиться даже при правильном ответе. ("не удивляйтесь что там чистое месево из калькулятора, квеста)")

Answer (score 3):

```
running = True
while running:
    slovo = input( "Введи кодовое слово, чел:" )

    if slovo == "Дружба":
        print ("Не разлей вода")
        running = False
    else:
        print ("Неправильно, друуг)")
```

в 6 строке добавил `running = False` чтобы выйти из цикла в случае если ответ верный
Также там не `for running` а `while running`
цикл `for` используется для итерации

```
while True:
    slovo = input( "Введи кодовое слово, чел:" )

    if slovo == "Дружба":
        print ("Не разлей вода")
        break
    else:
        print ("Неправильно, друуг)")
```

Вот второй вариант как сказал @ioprst

Comment: Можно использовать `while True` + `break`.

Comment: @ioprst + тоже можно